# Converting .kmz to .shp in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, shapefile, kml, kmz

How does one convert a .kmz or .kml to a shapefile using arcpy? tried the KMZ to Layer but it outputs a .lyr and a .gdb containing one feature class. I need a shapefile, or a way to convert the contents of the .gdb to a shapefile.

Answer (score 3):

A KMZ/KML can store multiple geometrie-types. A shapefile just one. I guess that is the reason for the FGDB output (multiple Feature Classes). So the FGDB can theoretically contain a point, line and polygon feature class. With `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses` and `arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion` a conversion is possible.

```py
import arcpy 
import os

def kmz2shapes(kmz, out_folder, temp_data_name):
    temp_gdb = os.path.join(out_folder, '{}.gdb'.format(temp_data_name))
    arcpy.env.workspace = temp_gdb

    arcpy.KMLToLayer_conversion(
        in_kml_file=kmz, 
        output_folder=out_folder,
        output_data=temp_data_name)

    fcs = [fc for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset='Placemarks')]
    arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(fcs, out_folder)


kmz2shapes("C:/path/to/data_test.kmz", "C:/path/to/kmz2shape", 'temp_data')
```

The function just converts the data to shapefiles and does not delete temporary data like the filegeodatabase and the lyr-files. There will be an error when executing the function twice with the same value for `temp_data_name`.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The KML To Layer tool will always output a File Geodatabase. I don't know why that is, but the documentation for the *Output Location* says (emphasis mine):

> Output location: The destination folder for the **file geodatabase** and layer (.lyr) file.

If you need a shapefile, you will need *KML To Layer* first, and then *Copy Features* (in the Data Management tools, under Features.

Comment: Is there any way to directly coy the layer or entire geodatabase to a shapefile? I'm working on a shitty laptop connected to a virtual desktop on campus so doing things in as few steps possible is ideal

Comment: Write a small arcpy script with these two commands? I'm not at a PC right now, or I'd have written a sample. But it's not hard, see https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/conversion-toolbox/kml-to-layer.htm and https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm